# How to delete columns in vi file?

Tags: linux, bash, vim, terminal, vi

I have a vi file containing hundreds of lines with the following format

```
029.inp.log:  SCF  Done:   E(RHF)  =   -844.790844670      A.U.  after    26 cycles
```

I want to delete all of the columns (separated by spaces/tabs. got messed up when I pasted it here) other than the first (029.inp.log:) and the fifth (-844.790844670). Can anyone help me?

Comment: Use `CTRL-v` and motion commands `h,j,k,l` to select columns and the delete them with `d`

Comment: Wrong site, not a programming question. Try http://superuser.com ?

Comment: or even more `vi` centric ... http://vi.stackexchange.com . Good luck.

Answer (score 18):

Press `ctrl+v` for block selection. use `h, j, k, l` keys to navigate and press key `d` to delete the selected block. The graphical editor like `kate` also having capability of the block selection.

Answer (score 7):

If you are not confined to vi, shell command is a good choice for this task.

`cat your_filename | cut -f 1,5 > result_filename`

About rectangle selection in vim, you must guarantee that the field in all lines with the same width.

Perhaps vim command 
`:%!cut -f1,5`   is OK too, but I can not give it a try now.